# data format in connection betwen desktop app and UWP application

Tags: c#, .net, networking, uwp, hololens

im creating a client-server service betwen desktop App (c#) and HoloLens (UWP).
The server runs on HoloLens, while PC App is the client.

I meet some problems with transfering data and here is my question to you.

While UWP server uses a Windows.Netowrking and Windows.Networking.Sockets, it seems to receive and send data as strings.
PC App uses System.Net and System.Net.Sockets and before sending the string it requires converting string into byte format.

Can this be an issue? I could not find to much documentation for Windows.Networking and i dont know if the data before sending is converted to byte anyway.

Comment: What makes you think the data is transmitted as strings? Sockets should be pure binary. Any non-binary data needs to be serialized to binary for transmission.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if the data before sending is converted to byte anyway

When you call Write() or Send() using a networking API, you normally get the option to provide many data types, be it a string or a byte[] or an int - but that doesn't affect how the data is physically transmitted.

Internally the transfer will be 'serialized' in an efficient manner (as a binary stream) but you don't need to care about those details.

Because the other end will be able to handle that data as a byte[], or an int[] or a string.

A common problem you might want to look into is [endianness](https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/), or checking how you are changing your string into a byte[].  ie problems where you're changing between strings, or different byte[]'s etc incorrectly.  You could read into [System.Text.Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.7.2) to check you are moving between byte[] and string correctly.

```
//Turn a string into a byte[], for your PC app to send
byte[] byteData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Message");
//On the other end read that byte[] into ASCII characters
char[] charsData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(byteData);
//Check you read something, and turn those chars into a string.
if (charsData != null && charsData.Length > 0)
    string stringData = new string(chars);
```